# iTunes connect upload issue (binary size)

Tags: app-store-connect, xcode6

I am trying to upload an update to an existing app I have in the appstore. 
I created an archive, passed validation and submitted the file via the Application Loader.

At the end of the upload I got the following message :

> The resulting API analysis is too large when upload app to mac store

Have no idea what it means and found some sources saying this is just a warning and it will not be rejected.

Looking in the build details of my uploaded build in the new itunes connect page I noticed that the file size is much smaller than the generated IPA file created by Xcode (2.69MB against 12.9MB)

And one last thing, under the Processing tab my uploaded build appears 4 times with status **'Created'** for each.

Did anyone bumped upon these issues above? I have a bad feeling that my build will be rejected for "Invalid Binary"...

Comment: The question is also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257597/the-resulting-api-analysis-is-too-large-when-upload-app-to-mac-store?rq=1 and looks like there is no answer as of the time I write the comment.

Comment: This is not exactly the same problem. The posted message is just part of it. I am more concerned from the file size.

Comment: The size problem is something that has also been "solved". It is wrong information in iTunes Connect.

Comment: @lnjuanj I hope so... I sent a request for the ITC support just in case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I contacted Apple support and they said they'll look into it... A few days after the file size in iTunesConnect has been updated to the right size and the app got approved a way long after;)

So apparently it was a glitch on the site so if some of you notice this, either wait a few days to be updated or contact the support (but don't try to reject and upload again as it will probably happen again until they fix it)